# Pass (password manager): Is it possible to show all the entry *except* the first line?

Tags: password-management

There is nice console password manager, "the ultimate Unix password manager", pass.

Not going much into details, there is a functionality to search in the database by name (`pass find`) and by contents (`pass grep`), to copy the password into buffer (`pass -c`) which only copies the first (or specified) line that normally contains the password. And you can show the whole entry with `pass show`, which, unfortunately, displays the whole entry, including the password.

My intent is to show everything about the entry *except* the first (or specified) line. It seems that is not possible, but maybe I am wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Following the spirit of 'pass' being a password manager that "follows Unix philosophy", I believe this would be the most appropriate method:

```
pass show <item> | sed 1d
```

alternatively,

```
pass show <item> | tail +2
```

Comment: Yes, that's possible and I thought about that. It's not convenient to type, though. Also not convinced that "unix pholosophy" applies here. Why a dedicated command to copy a concrete line into a clipboard exists then, and it even clears it after some time?